# Why is my For loop in python printing three times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I am trying to loop through a JSON file to get specific values, however, when doing so the loop is printing three times. I only want the value to print once and have tried breaking the loop but it still has not worked.

Python Code:

```
with open(filename) as json_filez:
  dataz = json.load(json_filez)
  for i in dataz:
   for i in dataz['killRelated']:
     print(i["SteamID"])
        break
```

and a snippet of my json file is

```
{
    "killRelated": [
        {
            "SteamID": "76561198283763531",
            "kill": "15,302",
            "shotacc": "16.1%"
        }
    ],
    "metaData": [
        {
            "test": "lol"
        }
    ],
    "miscData": [
        {
            "damageGiven": "2,262,638",
            "gamePlayed": "1,292",
            "moneyEarned": "50,787,000",
            "score": "31,122",
            "timePlayed": "22d 11h 56m"
        }
    ]
}
```

and this is my output:

```
76561198283763531
76561198283763531
76561198283763531
```

Expected output:

```
76561198283763531
```

Comment: Remove for i in dataz['killRelated']: and change print to print(dataz['killRelated']["SteamID"]). Also remove the break.

Comment: @user That won't work.

Comment: How many times do you think it should print? Why? In your own words, where you have `for i in dataz:`, what is the purpose of that? How many times do you expect that outer loop to run? Why? Where you have `for i in dataz['killRelated']:`, how many times do you expect that to run *per iteration of the outer loop*? Why? So how much output do you expect in total? Why?

Comment: You have superfluous loops there. You probably want just `for i in dataz['killRelated']: print(i['SteamID'])`.

Comment: What *should* the output be? Please show a minimal reproducible example - a *complete* JSON input that is big enough to showcase the behaviour you want from the code, as well as the problem with the existing code; and be explicit about the desired behaviour.

Comment: I expected both to run once, I used `for i in dataz` to loop through the entire json file and then `for i in dataz['killRelated']` to loop through the specific array.

Comment: The "loop through the entire JSON file" is the problem. For however many items exist in "the entire JSON file", you're looping through `killRelated`… There's no reason you'd need to loop through `killRelated` more than once…

Comment: Thank you @deceze that makes it more clear I thought I had to loop through the entire thing at first , would you be able to copy paste that as an answer so I can label it as the answer please ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return from `json.load` is a dictionary, and you are only interested in one entry in that, keyed by `'killRelated'`. Now the *"values"* against each dictionary entry are lists, so that is what you need to be iterating though. And each element of such a list is a dictionary that you can again access via a key.

So your code could be:

```py
with open(filename) as json_filez:
    dataz = json.load(json_filez)
    for kr in dataz['killRelated']: # iterate through the list under the top-level keyword
        print (kr["SteamID"])
```

Now in your sample data, there's only one entry in the `dataz['killRelated']` list, so you'll only get that one printed. But in general, you should expect multiple entries - and cater for the possibility of none. You can handle that by try/except of by checking key existence; here's the latter:

```py
with open(filename) as json_filez:
    dataz = json.load(json_filez)
    if 'killRelated' in dataz:          # check for the top keyword 
        for kr in dataz['killRelated']: # iterate through the list under this keyword
            if 'steamID' in kr:         # check for the next level keyword
                print (kr["SteamID"])   # report it
```

You were getting three output lines because your outer loop iterated across all keyword entries in `dataz` (although without examining them), and then each time within that also iterated across the `dataz['killRelated']` list. Your addition of `break` only stopped that inner loop, which for the particular data you had was redundant anyway because it was only going to print one entry.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is correct. You should check your json file or you can share your full JSON text. That would be a problem. I run you code with json snippet you provided and it works as expected.

```
import json

with open("test.json") as json_filez:
   dataz = json.load(json_filez)
   for i in dataz:
       for i in dataz['killRelated']:
           print(i["SteamID"])
```

and the result as blow:

```
76561198283763531
```

Comment: I will update the original question to put my full Json file in.

Comment: There's no case where `for i in dataz: for i in dataz['killRelated']` should ever make sense or be considered "correct"…